# intel xdk tap/click not working

Tags: android, html, cordova, intel-xdk

I have a problem using the intel xkd.
I used it for 2-3 month and it worked well.
Since the last update, my app doesn't work anymore.
The application works, but it seems that the device doesn't handle the tap on screen.
if i click on a button with the mouse on the pc it works, but i i tap it on the phone the event doesn't work.
I don't know why. 
if i start a new project from a default template the problem is still there so i think it's a problem related to the XDK/Cordova, but searching on their forum i didn't found nothing.

Comment: If you've made no changes to your app the build on a real device should still work. One thing that might have changed is the Cordova CLI version and or the versions of the plugins that are specified for the build. When you do the upgrade I believe it recommends you update your project to those new versions. Try building with different CLI versions on the Projects tab in the Build Settings section (options are 3.3, 3.5 and 4.1.2).

Comment: have you heard of debuggin? you can try it and check no errors are being thrown

Comment: Changing the CLI version doesn't solve the problem.
The debugger doesn't show any error.
I also found that i i use the chrome devices inspect, and i click on the screen emulator the app works.

Comment: I don't have much useful to add - although your problem sounds almost identical to this fellow's on the intel forums. He also started experiencing touch issues since the last update. Maybe keep an eye on the thread. https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/542976

Comment: I solved creating a new blank project.
I had to edit a bit the code, but now the tap is working

Comment: I just hit this issue, suddenly Intel XDK doesn't work with mouse clicks. If I build and deploy, it works fine on a device. I did a blank project and it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Check the js file via the embedded editor. There's a high probability that you will see errors/warnings. It could be a missing semicolon or an unclosed bracket.

Secondly, add onclick like this:

```
function Tap(){
alert("tapped");
}



<button onclick="Tap();">ClickMe</button>
```

Comment: I've tried almost everything but nothing fixed.
At the end, i tried to reinstall the xdk, and then all started to work again.
Probably something was corrupted.